# Saber si una ventana .dialog esta abierta

Tags: jquery-ui

tengo este código que abre ventanas de dialogo de jqueryui por la pagina.

```
function Ventanica(url,titulo,ancho,alto) { //configuro la ventanica
    if ($("#"+titulo).dialog('isOpen') === true) { $("#"+titulo).dialog("moveToTop") } else { //si la ventanuca ya esta abierta.
    $("<div id='"+titulo+"' class='loaderchachi'><div id='loader'>&nbsp;</div></div>").dialog({ "title" : titulo , "width" : ancho , "height" : alto ,close : function(){ $(this).dialog("destroy"); $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", "Ventanica('"+url+"','"+titulo+"','"+ancho+"','"+alto+"');"); $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("active").addClass("cerrado"); } })
    .dialogExtend({
    "autoOpen": false, "closable" : true, "maximizable" : true, "minimizable" : true, "collapsable" : false, "dblclick" : "maximize", "titlebar" : "transparent", "minimizeLocation" : "right",
    "icons" : {
        "close" : "ui-icon-close",
        "maximize" : "ui-icon-plus",
        "minimize" : "ui-icon-minus",
        "restore" : "ui-icon-bullet"
    },
    "load" : function(){
        $("#loader").html('<div class="loader-container"><div class="spinchachi"></div></div>');
        $("#"+titulo).load("/Paginas/"+url, function(response, status, xhr) { $("#loader").html('');
        if ( status == "error" ) { var msg = "Ocurrio un error al cargar contenido remoto: "; $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText , sticky : false, type : 'alert' }); }
        $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", '$("#'+titulo+'").dialog("moveToTop");');
        $("#dock"+titulo).addClass("active");
    });
    },
    "beforeMaximize" : function(evt) { EfectosmenuA(); $('#micromenusuario').css('top', 40); $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", '$("#'+titulo+'").dialogExtend("restore");'); $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("abierto").addClass("active"); },
    "beforeRestore" : function(evt){ EfectosmenuC(); $('#micromenusuario').css('top', 10); $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("abierto").addClass("active"); },
    "beforeMinimize" : function(evt) { $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("active").addClass("abierto"); },
 });
 } //cierro la condición de si es ventana nueva o primer plano
};
```

El caso es que quiero comprobar si ya esta abierta y si lo esta que lo que haga sea llevarla a primer plano. en principio con:

`if ($("#"+titulo).dialog('isOpen') === true) { $("#"+titulo).dialog("moveToTop") } else { //si la ventanuca ya esta abierta.`

lo compruebo y funciona. pero necesito que cargue el contenido nuevo de la ventana. creo que lo que carga contenidos esta dentro del "Load"

```
"load" : function(){
        $("#loader").html('<div class="loader-container"><div class="spinchachi"></div></div>');
        $("#"+titulo).load("/Paginas/"+url, function(response, status, xhr) { $("#loader").html('');
        if ( status == "error" ) { var msg = "Ocurrio un error al cargar contenido remoto: "; $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText , sticky : false, type : 'alert' }); }
        $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", '$("#'+titulo+'").dialog("moveToTop");');
        $("#dock"+titulo).addClass("active");
    });
```

el caso es que la condición de si esta abierto no tengo muy claro la sintaxis y donde poner el cierre de llave para que ejecute en vez de el abrir una ventana nueva, que la lleve a primer plano y que cargue el contenido nuevo. de momento lo he puesto justo antes del cierre de la función y lo lleva a primer plano, pero claro no carga nada.

¿Donde tendría que poner ese cierre de llave para que en vez de abrir lo lleve a primer plano y siga ejecutando el load?

he probado a ponerlo justo antes de "dialogExtended" pero me da un error de sintaxis que dice que me falta un . pero no se donde :_(

he probado a ver si el fallo era porque en `$("#"+titulo).dialog("moveToTop")` antes estaba cerrado con ; pero nada, da el mismo fallo.

¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he resuelto así:

```
function Ventanica(url,titulo,ancho,alto) { //configuro la ventanica
    if ($("#"+titulo).dialog('isOpen') === true) { 
        $("#"+titulo).dialog("moveToTop"); 
        $("#loader").html('<div class="loader-container"><div class="spinchachi"></div></div>');
        $("#"+titulo).load("/Paginas/"+url, function(response, status, xhr) { $("#loader").html('');
        if ( status == "error" ) { var msg = "Ocurrio un error al cargar contenido remoto: "; $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText , sticky : false, type : 'alert' }); }
        $("#dock"+titulo).addClass("active");
        });
    } else { //si la ventanuca ya esta abierta. 
    $("<div id='"+titulo+"' class='loaderchachi'><div id='loader'>&nbsp;</div></div>").dialog({ "title" : titulo , "width" : ancho , "height" : alto ,close : function(){ $(this).dialog("destroy"); $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", "Ventanica('"+url+"','"+titulo+"','"+ancho+"','"+alto+"');"); $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("active").addClass("cerrado"); } })
    .dialogExtend({
    "autoOpen": false, "closable" : true, "maximizable" : true, "minimizable" : true, "collapsable" : false, "dblclick" : "maximize", "titlebar" : "transparent", "minimizeLocation" : "right",
    "icons" : {
        "close" : "ui-icon-close",
        "maximize" : "ui-icon-plus",
        "minimize" : "ui-icon-minus",
        "restore" : "ui-icon-bullet"
    },
    "load" : function(){
        $("#loader").html('<div class="loader-container"><div class="spinchachi"></div></div>');
        $("#"+titulo).load("/Paginas/"+url, function(response, status, xhr) { $("#loader").html('');
        if ( status == "error" ) { var msg = "Ocurrio un error al cargar contenido remoto: "; $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText , sticky : false, type : 'alert' }); }
        $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", '$("#'+titulo+'").dialog("moveToTop");');
        $("#dock"+titulo).addClass("active");
    });
    },
    "beforeMaximize" : function(evt) { EfectosmenuA(); $('#micromenusuario').css('top', 40); $('.Li'+titulo).attr("onclick", '$("#'+titulo+'").dialogExtend("restore");'); $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("abierto").addClass("active"); },
    "beforeRestore" : function(evt){ EfectosmenuC(); $('#micromenusuario').css('top', 10); $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("abierto").addClass("active"); },
    "beforeMinimize" : function(evt) { $("#dock"+titulo).removeClass("active").addClass("abierto"); },
 });
    } //cierro el else de si esta abierto o no
};
```

No se si es la manera mas elegante, pero funciona.
Lo dejo publicado por si a alguien le sirve la respuesta o por si se os ocurre una manera mas elegante de solucionarlo.